# How do I calculate the times each combination of variable values in a dataframe occurs?

Tags: r, dataframe, combinations, distinct-values

I can use distinct() to get a dataframe of all the unique combinations and now I want to get the number of times each unique combination occurs. The actual dataframe I am using has over 10k combinations so I cannot calculate it manually.

```
n=1000000
X = rbinom(size=1,n,p=0.3)
U = rbinom(size=1,n,p=0.5) 
Y = rbinom(size=1,n,p=0.1)
dat<-data.frame(X, Y, U)
distinct(dat, X, U)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `dplyr::count` and also see `dplyr::add_count` like this:

```r
dplyr::count(dat, X, U)
# identical to
dplyr::group_by(dat, X, U) %>% 
  dplyr::summarise(n = n())

dplyr::add_count(dat, X, U)
```